# Who proved the monotone convergence theorem for the Lebesgue integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The theorem often be called Lebesgue's MCT or Levi's theorem. Who did originally prove it or what is the contribution of Lebesgue and Levi respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original version of the dominated convergence, from which the monotone convergence trivially follows *assuming that the limit is Lebesgue integrable*, was published by Lebesgue in [Leçons sur l'Intégration et la Recherche des Fonctions Primitives (1904)](https://archive.org/details/leconegrarecher00leberich). This is a compilation of his lectures at Collège de France over the preceeding five years.

In [Sopra l'Integrazione delle Serie](https://archive.org/stream/RendicontiIstitutoLombardoS2V39/Rendiconti_Istituto_Lombardo_S2V39#page/n805/mode/2up/search/775) (in Rendiconti - Reale Istituto lombardo di scienze e lettere, 39 (1906) 775-780) Beppo Levi quotes Lebesgue's result and notes that for positive monotone sequences one can drop the a priori integrability assumption for the limit. He then applies the result to sums of positive functional series, as the title indicates.

See also [Kubrusly, Essentials of Measure Theory, p.63](https://books.google.com/books?id=GffpCgAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) and [Chae, Lebesgue Integration, p.69](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uzf0BwAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s) for modern comments.